# CakePHP $this->element correct usage?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to make a reusable component (a weekday dropdown box, simple as pie) and am following the advice in http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements.

According to that page, I should make a blah.ctp file in app/views/elements, and it will be magically accessible in my view code as `$this->element('blah')`.

So I did it. I'm passing the form and field name to my element in the view code:

```
$this->element(
    'weekday_input', 
    array('form'=>$this->Form, 'fieldname'=>'weekday')
);
```

Earlier I created a form using `$this->Form->create`, so I figured I need to pass it to the element explicitly.

And my element code, in weekday_input.ctp:

```
echo $form->input(
    $fieldname, 
    array(
        'options', 
        array('Sunday'=>'Sunday',...,'Saturday'=>'Saturday')
    )
);
```

(Weekdays in between omitted for brevity.)

Am I using `$this->element` properly? Is there something more clean available?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the Form object. Form, Html and other helpers are available in elements (just as in view). Whether or not you want to pass fieldname depends: Do you need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

An element is a bit too simple I expect. Also it is not very testable. Would focus on Helpers, which is a more advanced way of developing this. But there is another solution I would prefer even more:

For this kind of issues it might be more appropriate to extend the formhelper itself. You can see a simple example here:

http://blog.nlware.com/2012/02/07/cakephp-2-0-how-to-extend-the-formhelper/

A full example can be found for example here:

https://github.com/slywalker/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/blob/master/View/Helper/BoostCakeFormHelper.php

As you asked for a clean solution think about creating a plugin (or check out existing plugins). That will separate the code out of your project more clean. And it will be available for re-use without much issues.

you can find all files needed for a plugin in the same project:
https://github.com/slywalker/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake

And the documentation here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html